# Fitting GTM with Nuxt route change with <nuxt-link>

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router, google-tag-manager

I have a problem implementing Google Tag Manager with Nuxt (SSR enabled). Where I want to trigger container loaded on every page where it hits a page change on `UA` or `G4A` and I have tried these set of implementations.

1. Implementing the library module of `@nuxtjs/gtm` where I have
   implemented `pageTracking: true` and tried implementing the trigger
   point of `nuxtRoute` via instructions from
   https://www.ericbroucek.us/blog/google-tag-manager-google-analytics-setup-with-nuxt/
2. Implementing

```
    __dangerouslyDisableSanitizers: ['script'],
          script: [
            {
              vmid: 'extscript',
              innerHTML: `(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
          new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
          j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
          'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
          })(window,document,'script','dataLayer',`${gtmID}`);`,
              type: 'text/javascript',
              charset: 'utf-8',
              defer: true } 
            },
          ],
```

on every page via the `vue-meta` head() feature

3. Implementing an `static/analytics.js` file filled with `gtm` default script code and then reference it via `nuxt.config.js`'s head object.
4. Implementing to manually load the script on every page

```
mounted() {
let gtm = document.createElement('script')
    gtm.type = 'text/javascript'
    gtm.text = this.googleDefaultFunctionScript
    document.head.appendChild(gtm)
}
```

When I load a page I am expecting these set sequence to load on initialization

[image: these sequence to load]

However when I hit `<nuxt-link>` button to navigate the website via `vue-router` to preserve states within the web app and expecting

[image]

but getting

[image]

instead.

As you can see that the page name doesn't change unless I navigate via `<a>` tag instead of `<nuxt-link>` tag. I want to be able to load the script sequence with every nuxt page I load.

Comment: You should clearly not do this with `appendChild` nor on every page (creating multiple instances). Did you try setting this one in the `nuxt.config.js` file?

Comment: @kissu yes I did, putting it in `nuxt.config.js` is the ideal way of importing these head function but I still experience the same issue.

Comment: Having it only in `nuxt.config.js`**only** and using `nuxt-link` is not working?

Comment: @kissu it is not outputting the expected outcome by clicking on nuxt-link to have container loaded